# Hide accounts with certain record type from everyone except a public group

Tags: account, record-type, visibility

Do you know how can I hide Account records from a certain record type  even from the owner and to make them visible only to a public group, this is the ORG conf:

- Accounts -> Private, Grant access using hierarchies
- Record type -> Archived
- Public Group -> "People who can see archived accounts"
- Sharing rule -> Grant access to accounts with that record type to the public group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owning user always has access to an account.  You will need to change the owner to prevent the original user from viewing it.